# get array value from get method

Tags: javascript, android, get

How to get separate values of array in javascript?

in one page:

`var c=new Array(a);     (eg: a={"1","2"})  window.location="my_details.html?"+  c + "_";`   and in my_details.html :

my_details.htm:

```
var q=window.location.search;     
alert("qqqqqqqqqqqqq " + q);    
var arrayList = (q)? q.substring(1).split("_"):[];       
var list=new Array(arrayList);     
alert("dataaaaaaaaaaaa " +  decodeURIComponent(list)   + "llll " );
```

But i am not able to get individual array value like list[0] etc
How to get it?

thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decodeURIComponent()` will return you a `String`; you need to do something like:

```
var delim = ",",
    c = ["1", "2"];

window.location = "my_details.html?" + c.join(delim);
```

And then get it back out again:

```
var q = window.location.search,
    arrayList = (q)? q.substring(1).split("_"):[],       
    list = [arrayList];     
    arr = decodeURIComponent(list).split(delim);
```

This will use the value of `delim` as the delimiter to make the `Array` a `String`. We can then use the same delimiter to split the `String` back into an `Array`. You just need to make sure `delim` is available in the scope of the second piece of code.

Comment: If you do `console.log(decodeURIComponent(list))` what do you see? Are the data items delimited by spaces?

Comment: But Now I am facing the problem with [1, value list[0] value. how to resolve that?

Comment: Do you mean that the `Array` you get out contains a nested `Array`?

Comment: nope, the value of arr[0] is "[1" instead of just "1". The value "[" gets added to arr[0].!!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try removing `list = [arrayList];`. And using `arr = decodeURIComponent(arrayList).split(delim);`.