# How to convert array parameters from url into an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, get

After decode GET parameters:

```
var query = decodeURIComponent(document.location.search)
```

I get:

```
a[0]=data&a[1][one]=data&a[1][two]=data&b=data
```

I need to convert it into an object like this:

```
myObject = {
    a : {
          0 : data,
          1 : {
              one : data,
              two: data
          }
    },
    b : data
}
```

I don't know how to do it. I am blank.

EDIT.
This problem is quite different from possible duplicates. Here I have an multidimensional array. I could split that very easily into this:

```
myObject = {
   "a[0]" : data,
   "a[1][one]" : data,
   //etc
}
```

but I don't need that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297765/make-a-javascript-array-from-url
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559075/get-array-value-from-get-method
See also http://quickhow.net/2012/code/how-to-convert-get-url-structure-to-array-and-reverse

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert URL parameters to a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Is `data` an identifier, or a string?

Comment: @Amit, data is a string

Comment: I think that input you are noting is not accurate for the expected new structure. I believe you have a `2` in the array where it should still be a `1` like such: `a[0]=data&a[1][one]=data&a[1][two]=data&b=data`

Comment: @Amit, my problem —I think— is quite different

Comment: @KennethSalomon, Thanks, I've edited the error.

Comment: I guess you're right, it does look a little different. Can you control the transport method of your object? If you could use json (as a request body, or a stringified query string) it would be much easier for you

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a temporary solution, surely an awful and not proper one. Till I have a better one, I will use this. I think It may be useful to someone.

Next, I share a version of a till two level dimensional array. But it can be adapted to a deeper one:

```
function getParams() {
    var query = decodeURIComponent(document.location.search.substring(1));
    var params = {},
        tokens,
        r = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    var key, value, match = [],
        re = /\[([^\]]*)\]/g;

    while (tokens = r.exec(query)) {
        value = tokens[2];
        key = tokens[1].split('[');
        key = key[0];
        match = [];
        while ( (  res = re.exec(tokens[1]) ) != null ){
           match.push(res[1])
        }

        if (match) {
            switch (match.length) {
                case 1 :
                    params[key] = params[key] || {};
                    params[key][match[0]] = value;
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    params[key] = params[key] || {};
                    params[key][match[0]] = params[key][match[0]] || {};
                    params[key][match[0]][match[1]] = value;
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            params[key] = value;
        }
    }

    return params;
}
```